# Reading a large-single XML line to a variable using Batch Script

Tags: batch-processing, batch-file

I have a xml file which only contains a single line, but the problem is the line is very large, so it seems that I can't store in a variable.

What i want is this,

given tag1, tag2.....tag900, I want to break each tag into a line as follow:

tag1

tag2

tag3

......

tag900

Comment: xml files don't have lines as such. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: What i want is to have a line break between each tag. For example, I have a xml file looks like this <a></a><b></b><c></c>, and I want to change the xml file to this: <a>\n</a>\n<b>\n</b>\n<c>\n</c>

Comment: That prettified view is available in lots of places and achieved with XSLT usually. If that's all you want your batch process to do, fine. If you are breaking it up into lines so you can process them as strings though, then follow @dbenham advice.

Answer (score 2):

Do not attempt to do this using native batch. It will be extremely difficult, and any solution will be very slow.

The problem is native batch cannot read lines > 8k, and batch does not have a good way to read partial lines.

There is a method that creates a test file that has size >= your file that consists of a single repeated character.  A binary file compare ( `FC /B` ) is then done and the results are parsed character by character expressed as hex codes. It's a bit more complex than that, but I don't think you want to go there.

The only other option is to use SET /P to read in 1021 chars at a time, and then parse and piece things together. But this is unproven, and again, I don't think worth the effort.

If you want to use a native scripting language than I suggest VBScript or JScript. (Perhaps PowerShell, but I don't really know much about its capabilities).

You could download a Unix text processing tool like sed that has been ported to Windows.

I don't do much with XML, but I've got to believe there is a free tool geared specifically for XML that would make your job fairly easy.

Basically, use anything *except* batch! (this is coming from someone whose hobby is solving problems with batch)